# How to open a file in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have been searching on [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/) to find out whether I can implement something similar to the image below but I couldn't find any. Please can anyone help me with this?

[image: File sharing]

Answer (score -1):

this is very simple you can pick any image from the folder then pastes it down on the Flutter project image folder then go to pub dependencies and then commit out the assets lines code and removes the path of the image and gives it to that folder the present in flutter project and picture also available than simply used it.

Comment: No, I am not trying to add it as an asset in my app. I want to implement a similar thing in my app. something like share_plus